# Finding the average of individual rows and columns in random array

Tags: c++, arrays

I've got to make a program that creates a 10x10 array of random numbers 0-9 and find the average of each individual row and column and also the whole array. I've got the array right but i'm stuck on how to select a single row or column then find the average of it, any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int numRows = 10;

const int numCols = 10;
int val[numRows][numCols];
int i, j;
double sum = 0, avgR, avgC;

void randNum() // Creates 10x10 array of random nums 0-9
{

    srand(2622); // random seed 

    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) // Creates random rows
    {
        cout << endl << endl;

        for (j = 0; j < numCols; j++) // Creates random columns
        {
            val[i][j] = rand() % 10;

            cout << setw(6) << val[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

}


void randAvg() // finds average of each row and column
{
    for (i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
    {
        sum += val[i][j];
    }

    avgR = sum / numRows;
    cout << "     " << avgR << endl;
}

int main() // calls each function
{

    randNum();
    randAvg();



}
```

Comment: Can you write code to compute the average for the first column?  For the first row?  If so, then you can look to using that code as a basis for a loop to do each row, and one to do each column.

Comment: And [what's wrong actually](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbb69a208a08c946)? What's your expected output?

Comment: Don't use global variables to share information among function calls BTW, rather use appropriate input/output parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two dimensional array has a row and a column. When you access each elements of such an array in a loop,it is better to reflect that structure with your loops.

So this in your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
{
        sum += val[i][j];
}
```

1. Is trying to access a single column(given by `j`) in each row(given by `i`) of your array
2. Since the value of `j` is now made **10** by the call to the `randNum()` function, you are accessing one element past your array (technically this happens when you are at the last row) which is not good. That is why it's not a good idea to use global variables to share information between functions.

With these:

```
//assuming sum and avgR are declared

//average of a row
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)//iterate each row(one loop for the row)
{
    sum=0;//reset sum for each row
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)//iterate each column in each row(one loop for the column)
            sum += val[i][j];//will sum up the contents of the current row

    avgR=sum/numCols;//give you the average of each row
}

//average of a column
for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)//iterate each column
{
    sum=0;//reset sum for each column
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)//iterate each row for each column
            sum += val[i][j];//will sum up the contents of the current column

    avgR=sum/numRows;//give you the average of each column
}
```

Am i sure you will be able to figure out how to get the average of the whole array.

Comment: This was what i needed, thanks so much for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

In either case, you will have to iterate over all array entries. While building the column average, you iterate over each column and in *each* iteration, you iterate over all rows, computing the average.
During the row average, you iterate over all rows and in *each* iteration compute the average over all columns:

```
void randAvg()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++)
    {
        float sum = 0.f;
        for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
            sum += val[i][j];
        }
        float avg = sum / numRows;
        cout << "Average of column " << i << ": " << avg << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        float sum = 0.f;
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            sum += val[j][i];
        }
        float avg = sum / numRows;
        cout << "Average of row " << i << ": " << avg << endl;
    }

    float sum = 0.f;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            sum += val[j][i];
        }
    }
    float avg = sum / (numRows*numCols);
    cout << "Overall average: " << avg << endl;
}
```

*Disclaimer: Untested code, should work though.*

Comment: Yeah this code works fine also, thanks for your help!